# Magento FPC and $_SESSION object

Tags: magento, caching, varnish, magento-fpc

How to use a cache when you have content depending on SESSION variable?
Does it work with Varnish-like cache? Does it require FPC?

let me explain.
My customers can select their model of Car (manufacturer, model, year), once selected this is stored in SESSION object.
(Of course every product is linked to a list of Cars in the back end.)

The thing is, on the frontend, There is a module that automatically filters the products according to the Car selected by the customer.

I'm not only talking about a user that would search for a product by entering a keyword on the search bar.
I'm also talking about the category pages.
When the customer visits the website, clicking on a category, then the list of products within this category is filtered too!
So while the customer navigates, he only see compatible products with his car.

I failed to use VARNISH because of this (VARNISH is based on url only, and the selected Car is not part of every url...).

That's why I'm wondering if there is any concept of Cache that would take into account SESSION variables?

thanks,
Rod